# Using library functions in home-made OS

Tags: c, operating-system, standard-library

I am interested in programming my own OS from scratch(in C).
However, every tutorial I encounter has made a message print on the screen by writing directly to the VDU. Why can't I use standard library functions while writing my OS? I don't have much problem in writing directly to the VDU. However, it sometimes makes my mind utterly confused(especially in large programs).

Are the library functions not converted into the same low-level code as the functions created by us?

Comment: Because I/O functions use the OS. And the standard library functions do not use *your* OS.

Comment: Also do you mean the *kernel*, or application programs? When you make the distinction, it is comparatively "trivial" to port a C library such as Newlib for your application programs

Comment: I mean 'kernel'.

Comment: @WeatherVane "_your_ OS"? Which OS does it really use?

Comment: @J...S the OS that OP is writing.

Comment: You want to use os functions . If you ask this question IMO it far too early for you to write own OS :)

Comment: My recollection is that output functions like printf() in glibc end up, by a tortuous route, in a call to sycall(), which stuffs certain values into registers and issues a trap to the kernel. You could, presumably, modify a library like glibc to link a syscall() implementation that is appropriate for another kernel -- but if you're writing a kernel, why use a big, heavy library to do something which your kernel must already be able to do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needsmuch more time to study language, OS-es, kernels etc before he will be ready for this task.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I don't think an arrogant "OP will not understand the answer" is a valid close reason.

Comment: @tofro you did not understand the reason. \one needs to have a quite vast knowledge for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of chicken-and-egg problem: Standard library functions use OS functions to print to the screen (deep down there, someone actually *needs to* write directly to the hardware).

Without an OS (because you just start writing one) this will not work. The standard library you want to use will need to be written specifically for and together with your OS.

Comment: ..or use the same syscall interface as one that already exists.